# Using Ruby BinData gem to read choices

Tags: ruby, binary-data, bindata

I am implementing a data structure using Ruby and the [BinData](http://bindata.rubyforge.org/) gem. I need to implement a `Choice` value. According to the BinData documentation, a choice can be implemented as:

```
class MyData < BinData::Record
  uint8  :type
  choice :data, :selection => :type do
    type key #option 1
    type key #option 2
  end
end
```

I need to have a default option in the choice:

```
class MyRecord < BinData::Record
    uint8 :type
    choice :mydata, :selection => :type do
            uint32 0
            uint16 1
    end
end
```

How can that be handled if `type` is not `0` or `1` in the above code?

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes any sense. What exactly do you need a "default" option for?

Comment: I am sorry about the question been ambiguous. Edited and added some more code sample to clarify it further.

Comment: OK, I see what you're trying to do. Your own answer below looks like a good solution. Go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found a work around. Anyway any other option is also most welcome.

```
class MyRecord < BinData::Record
    uint8 :data_type
    choice :mydata, :selection => :get_choice do
            uint32 1
            uint16 2
            string 255, :read_length => 4
    end

    def get_choice
            choices = [1, 2]
            if choices.include? data_type
                    return data_type
            else
                    return 255
            end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

BinData 1.4.1 handles this natively with `:default`

```
class MyRecord < BinData::Record
  uint8 :data_type
  choice :mydata, :selection => :data_type do
    uint32 1
    uint16 2
    string :default, :read_length => 4
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

you could set a default in a constructor perhaps...